# Right click menu under winforms

Tags: winforms, controls, menu

I want to make a right click menu for my winforms app. It will have the same two things in it no matter where it pops up. A little hunting and pecking leads me to the conclusion that winforsm either doesn't support this in a trivial way or has hidden it under some name I havn't guessed yet. I think I can make it work with the `Click` event and manually creating a menu in the right place, bla bla bla... Yuck, I can thing of a half dozon thing right now that I would get wrong the first time around. Someone has got to have a better way.

Am I missing some easy way to add this?

Is there some library/widget I can copy/paste in to handle the grunt work for me?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add a `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` item to the form, then set the form's `ContextMenuStrip` property.

Answer (score 4):

Put a `ContextMenuStrip` on your form, design your menu, then set the `ContextMenuStrip` property on the form to the component created.

Answer (score 3):

After putting a `ContextMenuStrip` on your form, Add it to your `Control` (you can do it in `Control`'s *Properties*) and then , use code like this for showing menu:

```
private void myTree_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     myTree.ContextMenu.Show(myTree, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
}
```

[more on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=netframework-4.7.2).